# Print functionality in php

Tags: php, printing

I have added print functionality on my page,
code:-

```
<input type="button" class="button-primary" onclick="printDiv('printableArea')" value="Print Application Report" style="position:relative;float:left" />
<script type="text/javascript">
            function printDiv(divName) {

                 var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;


                 var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

                 document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

                 window.print();

                 document.body.innerHTML = originalContents ;
            }

             </script>
if($_POST['from']=='' && $_POST['to']=='' && $_POST['select']=='Number of Applications'):?>
<div id="printableArea">

<table class="table table-bordered" align="center" style="width:200px !important;" border="1"> 
<h1 style="text-align:center">Application Report</h1>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="text-align:center;">Number of Applications</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php

$results2=$wpdb->get_results('SELECT COUNT( * ) as countme1 FROM table',ARRAY_A ); 
foreach ($results2 as $results1):?>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $results1['countme1'];?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach;?>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<?php endif;?>
```

when i click on print button of page then it take 2 pages in printing .last page is blank

please guide me why last page is blank.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP?

Comment: extra blank page i dont want.

Comment: You said that in the question. How does this relate to PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Call this printDiv function on click of print. and the below iframe to your html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function printDiv(divName) {
    var content = document.getElementById(divName);
    var pri = document.getElementById("ifmcontentstoprint").contentWindow;
    pri.document.open();
    pri.document.write(content.innerHTML);
    pri.document.close();
    pri.focus();
    pri.print();
  }
</script>
<iframe id="ifmcontentstoprint"></iframe>
```

Comment: Hello @daya i have 1 button for print

Comment: yes.. call this function on that button click

Comment: after "printableArea" div closing add iframe that i given, and call the javascript function that i given.. u should get a print

Comment: i get a print but 2 pages are coming in print. the extra last page is blank in printing .

Comment: even my code also giving you as 2 pages output?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53941/discussion-between-daya-and-user1988)